# Restoration of identical files from the recycle bin with the replacement or copying

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

As mentioned in header, my goal is to restore files from recycle bin with collisions handling.

I'm quite new to this API, so any tips about approach, that will allow me to resolve the collision(e.g. recycle bin contains two files with identical names but different size) automatically would be appreciated.

Right now I have unpleasant popup window, that is absolutely unacceptable.

[image: Popup]

Complete working example can be found here [here](https://gist.github.com/im-infamou5/03487b5b05336fcc69a1).

Comment: Restore them one at a time to a temporary folder. From there, you can move it to the final location, possibly with renaming.

Comment: @RaymondChen, this approach implemented, but I still hope, that some API trick to do it exists.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no proper API for restoring files from the recycle bin, so you just need to kludge it as best you can.

Comment: Simulating a drop is how you restore a Recycle Bin item to a specific folder.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Simulating a drop is not a proper API, it's a kludge. There's a function to put files in the recycle bin - why isn't there one to take them out again?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Because the model wasn't for apps to be sucking things out of the recycle bin. Users should be the ones doing that.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Even if it's the user who's driving the app? Explorer is not the beginning and end of the universe, you know.

Comment: @JonathanPotter The model is that the user drives the action by dragging and dropping. The app can drive the drag/drop.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Except when the user drives the action by pressing Ctrl-Z after deleting a file...